# Rewrite rule for -2 updating in all numeric slugs?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a Wordpress site where the url slug has to be numeric values only. I know this should typically be avoided but it's for a school project so I have no other way.

Wordpress automatically adds -2. I want to make a writerule that deletes -2 at the end of the URL slug only includes numbers but I'm not sure how.

A link in my website currently looks like this:

> http://localhost/woensdag-callerid/wordpress/06333911-2

I want it to look like this:

> http://localhost/woensdag-callerid/wordpress/06333911

And btw, no the -2 is not because of any duplicates. I cleaned my trashed files and it still shows so it's because of the all numeric slug I need to use.

Comment: _"And btw, no the -2 is not because of any duplicates."_ - pretty sure it is. _"I cleaned my trashed files"_ - what "files" are you talking about? Do you actually mean posts/pages? Just putting them into the trash bin is surely not enough here - they might get _restored_ at some later point, so I am pretty sure WP still keeps those old slugs "reserved."

Comment: I made sure there aren't any double pages and deleted the ones that were in trash status in my database.